# Aggregate Count on Grouped Data

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

I have document in which I have invoice numbers and a subdocument in which I specified that the type of invoice

```
{  
    "inum" : "001",
    "date" : "28-May-2017",
    "value" : 10020, 
    "section" : { 
        "B2C" : false, 
        "B2B" : true
    } 
},
{  
    "inum" : "001",
    "date" : "22-May-2017",
    "value" : 3400, 
    "section" : { 
        "B2C" : false, 
        "B2B" : true
    } 
},
{  
    "inum" : "034",
    "date" : "22-May-2017",
    "value" : 80500, 
    "section" : { 
        "B2C" : true, 
        "B2B" : false
    } 
}
```

Now I and grouping documents on the basis of Invoice numbers and I am grouping it with mongoose query and getting expected result.
so it will give me a single invoice with sum of `value` like below

```
{  
    "inum" : "001", 
    "value" : 13420, 
    "section" : { 
        "B2C" : false, 
        "B2B" : true
    } 
},
{  
    "inum" : "034",
    "date" : "22-May-2017",
    "value" : 80500, 
    "section" : { 
        "B2C" : true, 
        "B2B" : false
    } 
}
```

Now I want count of total invoice numbers of differnet section types after grouping , like above invoice no. has `B2B & B2C` section so it should give me

```
{"b2b":1,"b2c":1}
```

Above I can do by creating functions for all sections But I dont want to create functions for individuals I want mongodb query to get counts for all sections.

I did as below

```
{
               $group: {
                   _id : {inum:"$inum"},  
                   b2b:  {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq:["$section.B2B", true]}, 1, 0]}},
         b2c:  {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq:["$section.B2C", true]}, 1, 0]}},
               }
           }, 
{$project: {_id:0}},
```

its giving me count of unmergered Invoice numbers
`{ "b2b":2, "b2c":1 }`

But I want count after grouping data 
`{ "b2b":1, "b2c":1}`

Comment: If I understand your question you want the "merged" counts, correct? If so is there a case where the section data can differ for the same invoice. I.e presuming the first document is `{ "B2B": true, "B2C": false }` and the second document to "merge" is `{ "B2B": false, "B2C": true }`, what happens then? Are both true or both false? Or does this never happen and both documents to "merge" should have the same values?

Comment: No... Its   necessary   that section data can not be differ for the same invoice.... If an invoice is `B2B` true then it will be only for `B2B` no other section will true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want "two" [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages here. One using [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) for the "section" when grouping on "inum" and another grouping on `null` with the actual [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/):

```js
[
 { "$group": {
   "_id": "$inum",
   "section": { "$first": "$section" }
 }},
 { "$group": {
   "_id": null,
   "b2b": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$section.B2B", 1, 0 ] } },
   "b2c": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$section.B2C", 1, 0 ] } }
 }}
]
```

The first is just going to "merge" as your request and only keep the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) `"section"` data found.

The latter conditions do the accumulation over **all** documents since that is what `null` as a grouping key evaluates to do.

The [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) syntax here can be shortened sing the the first "if" condition of the ternary expression being examined is actually already a "boolean" `true/false` value. So no need for the additional comparison to coerce to a boolean.

Comment: Thanks... Its working but Some times its giving me some unexpected result. Let me look at this... by the way thanks

Comment: @SaurabhSharma You might "possibly" have an issue where not all the keys are present. You might think about including a initial `$match` stage with [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) on the specific keys used. Alternately you could expand on the aggregation logic with [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) where this is the case. If you still have a specific issue you cannot solve then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and someone will try to address it.